# What is tab #13119 on my VS 2008 toolbox?

Tags: visual-studio, telerik

I only noticed this last night, as I have not used the toolbox on this particular project for some time.  Suddenly, all my Telerik controls, previously on their own tab, were missing, and this mysterious, empty tab #13119 was there.  I added a new tab for Telerik and added all the controls, but the Telerik tab remained invisible, although the controls are still ticked to indicate that they are in the toolbox.

Comment: <sarcasm>Probably has something to do with the unbearable bugginess of the Telerik RadControls suite</sarcasm>

Comment: I'm not using any third party controls at all and I have this non-removable tab too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this now and again.
Try right clicking the Toolbox and select 'Reset Toolbox'

Comment: 'Reset Toolbox' doesn't help here.

Answer (score 10):

It seems to be a bug.

Citation from [here](http://zinovate.com/weblog/archive/2009/01/16/38234.aspx):

> 1. Make sure you can see all of the folders on your box. We are heading to the realm of hidden files: (Under Tools --> Folder Options)
> 2. Close Visual Studio if it is open.
> 3. Go Here: C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\
> 4. Backup the following files in a temp folder for saftey and delete the originals.
>      (toolboxIndex_reset.tbd ,toolboxIndex.tbd ,toolbox_reset.tbd ,toolbox.tbd)
> 5. Restart Visual Studio and the files will be recreated. It'll take a few seconds for the toolbox to repopulate.

Comment: You probably also need `Tools>Options>Windows Form Designer>AutoToolboxPopulate` set to true (which is the default value)

Comment: The location of the files on XP is C:\Documents and Settings\USER_NAME\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0

Comment: I followed the steps outlined above, but each time I open the IDE, if I click on Toolbox, it takes several seconds to "intialize" the toolbox, and it does not replace the .tbd files in my app data folder.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps: [Toolbox Missing Controls](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/490c9f52-f0c3-4fd3-9770-b8be9e0fd9d9/)